# Update single entry based on lookup in multiple sql tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update entries in a table to reflect what I have stored in another table, based on which category an item is in yet another table. Oh, and my items are keyed by both an alphabetic key (AKey) and numeric key (NKey).

So far I have

```
update itmHistory
set ithLocation = storLocation from items, storage
where ithAKey in (select storAKey from storage)
  and ithNKey in (select storNKey from storage)
  and storCategoryName = itmCategoryName;
```

What ends up happening is each instance of itmLocation in the items table is set to the very last entry where the `storCategoryName = itmCategoryName`.

Any ideas to make each update as it's found?

EDIT: Table information:

```
itmHistory: ithAKey varchar(3)   PK
            ithNKey int          PK
            ithStart timestamp   PK
            ithEnd timestamp
            ithLocation text

items:      itmAKey varchar(3)   PK
            itmNKey int          PK
            itmCategoryName text

storage:    storName text        PK
            storCategoryName text
            storLocation text
```

(PK = Primary Key)

Comment: Why `MySQL` in the list of tags? Is it relevant here?

Comment: Please, provide table definitions also

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table information, how about this one?

```
UPDATE ih 
SET ih.ithLocation = s.storLocation
FROM itmHistory ih
JOIN items i ON ih.ithAKey = i.itmAkey  AND ih.ithNKey=i.itmNKey
JOIN Storage s ON i.itemCategoryName = s.storCategoryName
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how a join actually works, can you explain it so I can know what kinds of problems can be solved by it in the future?